# Compare edge (must be the same and equal)

Tags: orientdb

I need to compare one specific vertex to all other and print if they have exactly the same outE("Pertinent", "Secondaire")

here is the request i made :

```
SELECT $b
let $a = (
  SELECT *
  FROM Regle
  WHERE titre="1823 - accessoires poids lourds tachygraphe"
),
$b = (
  SELECT *
  FROM Regle
  WHERE out("Pertinent", "Secondaire") = $a.out("Pertinent", "Secondaire")
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
SELECT expand($b)
let $a = (
  SELECT *
  FROM Regle
  WHERE titre="1823 - accessoires poids lourds tachygraphe"
),
$b = (
  SELECT *
  FROM Regle
  WHERE out("Pertinent").@rid in $a.out("Pertinent").@rid and out("Secondaire").@rid in $a.out("Secondaire").@rid
)
```

Hope it helps.